# Strongloop Complex Queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have this SQL query:

```
    SELECT cvs.overview, 
        usr.username, usr.email, usr.id, 
        usrd.firstname, usrd.lastname, usrd.profilepicture, usrd.hourlyrate,
        skill.name AS skill
    FROM public."Cvs" AS cvs
    LEFT JOIN public."Users" AS usr ON cvs.usersid = usr.id
    LEFT JOIN public."UserDetails" AS usrd ON usr.id = usrd.usersid
    LEFT JOIN public."Cvs_Skills" AS cvskill ON cvs.id = cvskill.cvsid
    LEFT JOIN public."Skills" AS skill ON cvskill.skillid = skill.id
    WHERE usr.username ILIKE '%node%'
      OR skill.name ILIKE '%node%'
```

I need to know how to do it in the Strongloop ORM way

Comment: If you feel like my answer has helped you, feel free to accept it. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You should step away from thinking in SQL queries with loopback. SQL queries are abstracted, well, because there is an ORM that does just that.

Instead, define models like

- `MyUser` with properties like `firstname`, `lastname`, `profilepicture`, `hourlyrate`,
- `Skill` with property `name` for instance

Then, create a relation `MyUser` `hasMany` `Skill`, etc. Afterwards, you will be able to query all skills for a given user, add new skills to a user, etc.

This is just to get you started, you should take the time to read the [documentation](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/index.html) to understand how to work with loopback, and how to do everything I just mentionned. This is basic stuff so you will have not trouble doing it.